# ESS error: could not find function .help.ESS

Tags: emacs, ess

I am using Emacs 24.3.1 on Windows with ESS v13.05 and with `autocomplete`. While this pops up completion candidates for me, it doesn't show the help.

```
Error: could not find function ".help.ESS"^M
```

[image: ess help error]

Following the advice in [this post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/ess-help/2010-August/006277.html) I tried typing the following in the ESS R process terminal:

```
.help.ESS <- help
```

As a result, if I linger on a function like `merge`, it will launch the relevant help page in the browser.

It's tedious to have to type this every session. How can I ensure that the `.help.ESS` object is defined without my direct intervention?

Answer (score 0):

There is no .help.ESS in ESS anymore. The most recent version of ESS and stable 13.09 both work fine. Please upgrade.

Also please report any issues to ess-help or git bug tracker. Stackoverflow is not an appropriate place for this.

Comment: I have installed ESS 13.09 and I get the same error. With all due respect for your efforts, I disagree that Stack Overflow is not an appropriate place for this: it is far more popular and far more useful/transparent in search engine terms than the two alternatives you mention. Obviously, I can't insist that you use SO, but it **is** a better place for questions that are not obviously bug reports.